# Styled Component devtools with React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, debugging, styled-components

Please help, `babel-plugin-styled-components` is not working. Here is `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
}
```

I tried to use `typescript-plugin-styled-components` however, it looks like I would need to eject, which I don't want to do. I used `create-react-app` to initialize the project. Any idea how to get this to work?

My css classes are all generated by styled components and making it difficult to style on the development side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Updated all `import styled from 'styled-components'` to `import styled from 'styled-components/macro'`
2. Installed `babel-plugin-macros`